# External JS not linking to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple directory structure with an `index.html` file and a `main.js` file at the same level and no other files/folders. But I'm unable to link this js file in my index.html.

I have posted the contents of both files below, and the expected behaviour is to have a simple alert pop-up.

**Here is my HTML File:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="main.js"></script>
        <title>External JS Issue</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Some Content Here.
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Here is my JS File:**
`alert("If you can read this, it worked!");`

---

However, if I include this JS line of code and put it directly inside my `index.html`, it works fine.
Here are the screenshots:  
index.html:
[image: index.html]

main.js:
[image: main.js]

Browser Screenshot with External JS(NOT Working):
[image: Browser Screenshot with External JS(NOT Working)]

---

index.html with inline JS:
[image: index.html with inline JS]

Browser Screenshot with Inline JS(Working):
[image: Browser Screenshot with Inline JS(Working)]

Comment: Any messages in the developer console?

Comment: Open your dev tools and see if file is loaded in your resources. If not your path is not ok, try using   ../main.js

Comment: @epascarello No, there's no message in developer console. I've tried ```console.log()``` too. I've made sure that both files are UTF-8 encoded. Still doesn't work

Comment: @ikiK No, that wasn't the issue. @geekonaut posted the answer, it was a type :p. I wrote ```scr``` instead of ```src``` in ```<script>``` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, the attribute of the `<script>` tag should be `src`, not `scr`.

Comment: Oh my god! How did I miss that?! Thanks a lot, spent over an hour looking it up